# Libre office is not auto capitalising or automatically putting in apostrophes

Tags: libreoffice

I have looked everywhere online and all I can find is people complaining that LibreWriter autocapitalises too much. It doesn't do it at all for me, and its driving me mad.

Anyone else had a similar problem? I've been trying to install openoffice instead but to no avail.

I hate to say it, but windows and microsoft word are gonna crawl back onto my laptop soon :'(

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you've turned off auto capitalization by a mistake? If this is the case, you can turn it on again with [this](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Turning_Off_AutoCorrect) method:

1. Choose **Tools** – **AutoCorrect Options**.
2. Click the **Options** tab
3. Check the "Capitalize first letter of every sentence" check box.

Also you should check out Word Online before you consider installing MS office suite, since Word Online is platform independent and free if I recall correctly.

Comment: nah, i havent done anything, i only installed ubuntu the other day and this is the first time ive used libre office at all

Comment: I recommend you take a look anyway and see if it's checked. It can possibly be trigged by a key-combination by mistake. If that doesn't fix it, please post a screenshot of the text so we can see for ourselves.